# Url.RouteUrl from an Html helper extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm extending `Html.HtmlHelper` to render the breadcrumb depending on the page I am:

```
public static HtmlString RenderBreadCrumb(this HtmlHelper helper, PageType pagetype, object Model)
```

How do I use `Url.RouteUrl` inside of an HtmlHelper to render the URL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create a new UrlHelper instance using a request context.

```
UrlHelper Url = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
Url.RouteUrl(…);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make a UrlHelper extension instead:

```
public static string RenderBreadCrumb(this UrlHelper helper, PageType pagetype, object Model)
```

Then call via:

```
 @Url.RenderBreadCrumb(pageType, Model)
```